# Dropzone autoprocess queue false not working if there is an error like maxfilesize,maxfileuploads etc

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload, dropzone.js

When I upload image of more size then permitted in dropzone autoprocessqueue does not works and shows process completed if I upload proper file then it works proper.Following is my code :

```
 Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = 
   { 
            url: 'file-upload.php',
            previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
            uploadMultiple: true,
            parallelUploads: 100,
            maxFiles: 100,
            maxFilesize: 5,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            autoProcessQueue: false, 
            acceptedFiles:'image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png',

            init: function()
            {
                thisDropzone = this;

                this.on("queuecomplete", function (file) {
                    alert("all files uploaded successfully");
                });


            }
        }


     });

    function process_queue() 
    {

        if(thisDropzone.files.length > 0) {
            thisDropzone.processQueue()
        }

    }
```

It triggers alert "all files uploaded successfully" if I upload big file or other file except image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.on("queuecomplete", function (file)   {    
  var size = thisDropzone.files[0].size/1000000;    
  if(thisDropzone.files[0].type== "image/jpeg"  ||thisDropzone.files[0].type=="image/jpg" || thisDropzone.files[0].type=="image/png" && size<5)
                        listingSubmitted(); 
 });
```